# Display: Inline Block not working properly

Tags: css

The problem is that when I use display inline-block it doesn't move all the boxes at once on a mobile screen (It has 3 boxes called "single-facilities"). The thing is that they move one at a time. I'm using display inline-block on media screen.

HTML:

```
<div class="box-facilities">

            <div class="single-facilities">
                <div class="img-facilities"></div>
                <div class="text-facilities">
                    <h1>World Class Library</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm
                    od tempor.</p>
                </div><!--facilities-text-->
            </div><!--single-facilities-->

            <div class="single-facilities">
                <div class="img-facilities"></div>
                <div class="text-facilities">
                    <h1>Largest Play Ground</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm
                    od tempor.</p>
                </div><!--facilities-text-->
            </div><!--single-facilities-->

            <div class="single-facilities">
                <div class="img-facilities"></div>
                <div class="text-facilities">
                    <h1>Tasty and Healthy Food</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm
                    od tempor.</p>
                </div><!--facilities-text-->
            </div><!--single-facilities-->

        </div><!--box-facilities-->
```

CSS:

```
        .box-facilities{
        display: flex;
        height: 800px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    
    .single-facilities{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .img-facilities{
        background-color: gray;
        width: 27rem;
        height: 27rem;
        border-radius: 1.5rem; 
    }
    
    .text-facilities{
        margin-top: 1rem;
        max-width: 28rem;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1370px){
    .box-facilities{
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the motive behind why you have used `display: flex` in the mobile version and `display: inline-block` in the other

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the direction to `column` as

```
flex-direction: column;
```

```css
.box-facilities {
  display: flex;
  height: 800px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.single-facilities {
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-facilities {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 27rem;
  height: 27rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

.text-facilities {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  max-width: 28rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1370px) {
  .box-facilities {
    /* display: inline-block; */
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box-facilities">

  <div class="single-facilities">
    <div class="img-facilities"></div>
    <div class="text-facilities">
      <h1>World Class Library</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm od tempor.</p>
    </div>
    <!--facilities-text-->
  </div>
  <!--single-facilities-->

  <div class="single-facilities">
    <div class="img-facilities"></div>
    <div class="text-facilities">
      <h1>Largest Play Ground</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm od tempor.</p>
    </div>
    <!--facilities-text-->
  </div>
  <!--single-facilities-->

  <div class="single-facilities">
    <div class="img-facilities"></div>
    <div class="text-facilities">
      <h1>Tasty and Healthy Food</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm od tempor.</p>
    </div>
    <!--facilities-text-->
  </div>
  <!--single-facilities-->

</div>
<!--box-facilities-->
```